# using a custom module, how to add a <style> tag after the theme's css files

Tags: theming

I use Drupal 6.

Everytime I use `drupal_set_html_head`, my `<style>` code is being added before my theme's `<link>` entries.

Basically, I want to override the theme's css files with internal css, so I need my `<style>` to appear at the very end of `<head>`

I hope it is clear. Thanks!

Comment: You could always use css specificity to override the theme's style rules. It might not be optimal, but it will save you from editing the template files.

Comment: How do you use css specificity with modules?

Comment: There's not a specific module way. Just override by using a higher specificity, a lazy way would be to copy the rules you want to override and add another class or id in the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you add with `drupal_set_html_head()` is added before the CSS styles added with `drupal_add_css()`. In fact, the [page template](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/6) outputs them using the following code.

```
<head>
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
  <script type="text/javascript"><?php /* Needed to avoid Flash of Unstyled Content in IE */ ?> </script>
</head>
```

`$head` and `$styles` are initialized in [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6) with the following code.

```
$variables['head'] = drupal_get_html_head();
$variables['styles'] = drupal_get_css();
```

As [drupal_add_css()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/6) is used to add all the CSS styles used by a theme, including the ones defined in its .info file, you can change the order the CSS styles are added by changing the page template. If it would contain the following code, everything added with `drupal_set_html_head()` will come after everything added with `drupal_add_css()`. I would not suggest doing this, if not after verifying it doesn't cause any problem.

```
<head>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
  <script type="text/javascript"><?php /* Needed to avoid Flash of Unstyled Content in IE */ ?> </script>
</head>
```

Notice that with Drupal 7, you can use [drupal_add_css()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) to use inline CSS style too: Just pass the CSS styles as first argument, and pass `array('type' => 'inline', 'weight' => 100)` as second argument. You need also to use the group property. In that way, you don't need to alter the template file just to add your CSS  styles after the ones added by Drupal.
Generally, it is preferable to add the CSS styles in a file; in that way, they can be aggregated/compressed.

Comment: thank you kiamlaluno. This is definitely the correct conclusion regarding my problem. I ended up creating a custom variable on mymodule_preprocess_page(), and then echoing it on the theme page.tpl.php. I really wanted to do it without changing anything on the theme files, but I guess i have no other options :)

Comment: `drupal_add_css` for D7 allows you to specify the weight which makes it possible to place the stylesheets in whatever order you'd like. This might not help you now since you use D6, but it might be good to know for future reference (if you upgrade).

Comment: thank you for that information hampusn. I will certainly make use of it in the future.